# log4net configuration: Can I refer to the same layout in several appenders?

Tags: log4net

I want to send log messages to several files (i.e. different appenders) based upon some property of the message.

The problem is that each `appender` needs to specify quite a verbose `layout` (that contains a compication conversionPattern and a couple of converters).  I have ended up duplicating this configuration in each `appender`.  This works but is not ideal as it makes the config much longer than I would like as well as the pain of having to update 3 complicated bit of configuration when the layout changes.

I want to be able to define the layout once and have all my appenders refer back to that one definition (in the same way that several loggers can refer to the same appender).  But perhaps there is a better way to achieve my goal of reducing duplication in the configuration?

My google-foo is weak and I could not find an answer.   Can anyone here help?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry but unless you are ready to code your own `Layout` class there is currently no way to skip on the copy-pasted configuration.

You can inherit from the `LayoutSkeleton` to get started, and either build your layout in code or use an alternate configuration file (I don't think that log4net would be kind to a dangling layout configuration in its config file)

Comment: Writing a Layout class is a good solution, unless the OP needs to be able to change the layout in config..

Comment: @stuartd Yes, that's why I was talking about another configuration file only for the layout; I think that a complex enough system may very well deserve its own configuration but then you lose on the native observable mechanism of log4net. Good point to remind though.